# MySQL "Incorrect index name..." error (unique foreign key)

Tags: mysql

I keep getting an error "Incorrect index name 'f7'" using MySQL and I've narrowed it down to the following:

First I create the table,

```
CREATE TABLE testTable (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    f7 INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (f7) REFERENCES testTable2 (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

And then elsewhere,

```
ALTER TABLE testTable ADD UNIQUE f7;
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312083/mysql-unique-foreign-key) has led me to believe that this has to do with a duplicate index (?) I just can't figure out how to fix it. Many thanks.

Comment: What are you doing when you receive this error?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Give it a name, so it doesn't conflict with the foreign Key index

```
ALTER TABLE `testtable`  ADD UNIQUE INDEX `foo` (`f7`);
```

Answer (score 7):

An `incorrect index name` error is given when you're attempting to create a new index with the same name as an existing index.

In MySQL, when you create a foreign key, as you're doing with `FOREIGN KEY (f7) REFERENCES testTable2 (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE`, an index is auto-created as well. In this case, the name is defaulted to `f7`.

The foreign key is created as a non-unique index; your second command: `ALTER TABLE testTable ADD UNIQUE (f7);` will make this index unique - not add a second one.

To verify what indexes already exist on the table, you can use the following:

```
SHOW INDEXES FROM testTable;
```

If you're receiving this error, there is likely additional code elsewhere that is attempting to create an index named `f7`. You can attempt to find it, or change your `CREATE TABLE` syntax to name the key something different so that it doesn't cause conflicts:

```
FOREIGN KEY fk_testTable_f7 (f7) REFERENCES testTable2 (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

In this example, I used `fk_testTable_f7` and you should now have a non-unique index on the table named `fk_testTable_f7`. To make it unique, you can use your existing `ALTER` command as you want the column to be unique - not the foreign key itself.