# Compose unique key on multiple foreign keys

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Given these SQLAlchemy models:

```
class Key():
    key_id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String(255))

class House():
    house_id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String(255))

class HouseKey():
    house_key_id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    house_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('house.id'))
    key_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('key.id'))

    UniqueConstraint('house_id', 'key_id')

    house = relationship('House', foreign_keys=[house_id])
    key = relationship('Key', foreign_keys=[key_id])
```

The `house_id, key_id` unique key isn't being created. I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312083/mysql-unique-foreign-key) is why (please correct me if I'm wrong).

How can I create a composite unique key on columns that are also foreign keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table-level `UNIQUE` constraints go in [`__table_args__`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/table_config.html#table-configuration):

```
class HouseKey(Base):
    ...
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint("house_id", "key_id"),)
```